# how to add user input to 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a small program to calculate the addition of two vectors from the user and storing it in the array.
I want to get two X and Y's (like this {x,y})from the user and then add them both together.

I tried to use a 2D array like so

```
int[,] array = new int[0, 1] {};
```

but I want the user to enter the values of it.
I don't know enough about c# so if anyone knows how can I solve this problem would apparitions your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a vector from user, you can try asking user to provide its components separated by some delimiter(s), e.g.

```
  private static int[] ReadVector(string title) {
    while (true) { // keep asking user until valid input is provided
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        Console.WriteLine(title);

      string[] items = Console
        .ReadLine()
        .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', ';', ',' }, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      if (items.Length <= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("You should provide at least one component");

        continue; 
      } 

      bool failed = false; 
      int[] result = new int[items.Length];

      for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; ++i) {
        if (int.TryParse(items[i], out int value))
          result[i] = value;
        else {
          Console.WriteLine($"Syntax error in {i + 1} term");
          failed = true;

          break;
        }  
      }

      if (!failed)
        return result; 
    }
  }
```

Then you can use this routine like this:

```
  // We don't want any 2D matrices here, just 2 vectors to sum
  int[] A = ReadVector("Please, enter vector A");
  int[] B = ReadVector("Please, enter vector B");  

  if (A.Length != B.Length) 
    Console.WriteLine("Vectors A and B have diffrent size");
  else {
    // A pinch of Linq to compute C = A + B 
    int[] C = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => a + b).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", A)}] + ");
    Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", B)}] = ");
    Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", C)}]");  
  }
```

**Edit:** Sure you can sum vectors with a help of good old `for` loop instead of Linq:

```
   int[] C = new int[A.Length];

   for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; ++i)
     C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
```

Comment: большое спасибо, this is exactly what I wanted and works perfectly, but still don't quite understand the whole code so I will try to go through it agian and again.

Comment: One more question, Is there any other way to do the last calculation other than using Linq?

Comment: @Rasta Mosi: sure, you can use good old `for` loop to sum corresponding components

Comment: `C[0]=A[0]+B[0]; C[1]=A[1]+B[1];` or you can use `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)C[i]=A[i]+B[i];`